# kendo ui diagram handler customization

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Diagram in my application. I am trying to remove padding between the shape and their handler (handler - dotted line around the shape for selecting the shape please look at attached image below)

[image]

Comment: There is around 20px padding around shape, that I need to remove

Comment: There is not such option in API. In shape edge there is place for connectors and if you remove it they would overlap.